# How to close the extension yellow ribbon in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I am doing automation using Selenium on Chrome browser. I installed a Chrome extension specific to my product. I am getting the yellow ribbon at the top and preventing me from accessing the page elements. Attaching the screenshot. How to close/prevent the ribbon from showing up?

[image]

Comment: sorry, dont know what to do then.  I guess i misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a specific flag / command line switch to do so.

> ```
> --silent-debugger-extension-api
> ```
>
> Does not show an infobar when an extension attaches to a page using chrome.debugger page. Required to attach to extension background pages.